# Python Listing Files Numerically

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a set of files.

In each file, there is a column that corresponds to a file number. They all are named in this format:

```
test_file_page_#_out_of_7000.txt
```

Example:

```
test_file_page_1_out_of_7000.txt
test_file_page_2_out_of_7000.txt
test_file_page_7000_out_of_7000.txt
```

When I run the following code:
output_pages = os.listdir()

The files are listed in this order:

```
'test_file_Page_10_out_of_7000.txt', 'test_file_Page_11_out_of_7000.txt', ..., 'test_file_Page_1_out_of_7000.txt', 'test_file_Page_2_out_of_7000.txt'
```

I would like the files listed in this order:

```
'test_file_Page_1_out_of_7000.txt', 'test_file_Page_2_out_of_7000.txt', ..., 'test_file_Page_10_out_of_7000.txt', 'test_file_Page_11_out_of_7000.txt'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sorted` method takes a `key` argument, which is a function that takes a list element and returns the value that should be used for sorting:

```
def get_number(filename):
    return int(filename.split("_")[3])
    
files = sorted(os.listdir(), key=get_number)
```

Comment: This works perfect, I'll accept it as the answer in 5 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: Question though, why does key=get_number work? Why is it not key=get_number(os.listdir()) or something else passed? The function has a parameter and it doesn't appear to be passing one, even though it is passing one.

Comment: Great question. The `sorted` function takes the `key` function you give it and uses it internally when sorting the elements. So it's not actually our responsibility to call that function, it's `sorted`'s.